# How to convert list to string

Tags: python, string, list

How can I convert a list to a string using Python?

Comment: `str(anything)` will convert any python object into its string representation. Similar to the output you get if you do `print(anything)`, but as a string.

Comment: So one way to make this different than that one is to suggest using json to do it like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796446/convert-a-list-to-a-string-and-back.  Using json easily allows the reverse process (string to list) to take place.  But the OP really did need to explain themselves.  Is it for display only or some other purpose?

Comment: Please give an example of the format you want.

Comment: Use json.dumps(SOME_LIST) if you want [1,2,3] to become "[1,2,3]". For example, if you wanted to insert the list into a data table column that accepts strings.

Answer (score 1970):

Use `''.join`:

```
xs = ['1', '2', '3']
s = ''.join(xs)
```

---

If the list contains integers, convert the elements to string before joining them:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3]
s = ''.join(str(x) for x in xs)
```

Comment: @SenthilKumaran If the resulting string requires separate items such as when passing a list of files to a process, then "" has to be changed to " " (notice the space between the quotes). Otherwise, you end up with a contiguous string ("123" instead of "1 2 3"). This is OK if that was the intention, but needs to be mentioned in the response.

Comment: Just gonna point out that the second form works fine on almost any (single-depth) list.

Comment: I was looking for this here and found it [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560863/python-join-with-newline): If you want to have a newline for every list element (might be useful for long-string lists): `print ("\n".join(['I', 'would', 'expect', 'multiple', 'lines']))`

Comment: The question may be a duplicate but the answer here is better than there. :) Plus this pops up as the top result on google unlike the other. (which I've noticed a lot with dupes)

Comment: Agree with @Bogdan. This answer creates a string in which the list elements are joined together with no whitespace or comma in between. You can use `', '.join(list1)` to join the elements of the list with comma and whitespace or `' '.join(to)` to join with only white space

Comment: You can use it with parsing all of the cmd arguments, with `test = sys.argv[1:]` and then the `join` method.

Comment: `str(anything)` will convert any python object into its string representation. Similar to the output you get if you do print(anything), but as a string.

Answer (score 431):

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3]       
>>> " ".join(str(x) for x in xs)
'1 2 3'
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use: >>> " ".join([str(x) for x in L])

Comment: `str(anything)` will convert any python object into its string representation. Similar to the output you get if you do print(anything), but as a string.

Answer (score 133):

```
xs = ['L', 'O', 'L']
lol_string = ''.join(map(str, xs))
```

Comment: it throw `TypeError` exception,like this:
     In [15]: L=['1','2','3']

In [16]: print ''.join(map(str,L))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f3b8e6cb2622> in <module>()
----> 1 print ''.join(map(str,L))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Since it wasn't specific in the question... If you want to preserve single string quotes on your list items (for sending a query to SQL, for instance), you can do something like this. 

`x = [1,2,3]`
`y = "'" + "','".join(map(str, x)) + "'"`

Comment: Anyone who is trying to re-use the string after converting the list to string can you this method:

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
str1 = ''.join('hello world' + str(e) + 'hello world' for e in list1)

Output
===========
hello world 1 hello world
hello world 2 hello world
hello world 3 hello world

Comment: `str(anything)` will convert any python object into its string representation. Similar to the output you get if you do print(anything), but as a string.