# Python - Join with newline

Tags: python, string

In the Python console, when I type:

```
>>> "\n".join(['I', 'would', 'expect', 'multiple', 'lines'])
```

Gives:

```
'I\nwould\nexpect\nmultiple\nlines'
```

Though I'd expect to see such an output:

```
I
would
expect
multiple
lines
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The console is printing the representation, not the string itself.

If you prefix with `print`, you'll get what you expect.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for details about the difference between a string and the string's representation. Super-simplified, the representation is what you'd type in source code to get that string.

Answer (score 55):

You forgot to `print` the result. What you get is the `P` in [`RE(P)L`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) and not the actual printed result.

In Py2.x you should so something like

```
>>> print "\n".join(['I', 'would', 'expect', 'multiple', 'lines'])
I
would
expect
multiple
lines
```

and in Py3.X, print is a function, so you should do

```
print("\n".join(['I', 'would', 'expect', 'multiple', 'lines']))
```

Now that was the short answer. Your Python Interpreter, which is actually a REPL, always displays the representation of the string rather than the actual displayed output. Representation is what you would get with the `repr` statement

```
>>> print repr("\n".join(['I', 'would', 'expect', 'multiple', 'lines']))
'I\nwould\nexpect\nmultiple\nlines'
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to `print` to get that output.
You should do

```
>>> x = "\n".join(['I', 'would', 'expect', 'multiple', 'lines'])
>>> x                   # this is the value, returned by the join() function
'I\nwould\nexpect\nmultiple\nlines'
>>> print x    # this prints your string (the type of output you want)
I
would
expect
multiple
lines
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to print it:

```
In [22]: "\n".join(['I', 'would', 'expect', 'multiple', 'lines'])
Out[22]: 'I\nwould\nexpect\nmultiple\nlines'

In [23]: print "\n".join(['I', 'would', 'expect', 'multiple', 'lines'])
I
would
expect
multiple
lines
```

Answer (score 4):

When you print it with this `print 'I\nwould\nexpect\nmultiple\nlines'` you would get:

```
I
would
expect
multiple
lines
```

The `\n` is a new line character specially used for marking END-OF-TEXT. It signifies the end of the line or text. This characteristics is shared by many languages like C, C++ etc.

Answer (score 1):

The repr() function returns a printable representation of the given object and is crucial for evalStr() or exec in Python; for example you want to get out the Zen of Python:

```
eng.execString('from this import *');
println('import this:'+CRLF+
  stringReplace(eng.EvalStr('repr("".join([d.get(c,c) for c in s]))'),'\n',CRLF,[rfReplaceAll]));
```