# Python - Concatenate Two Strings Separated by Double Newline

Tags: python, string, list

I currently have a list, one index of which contains a double newline (`\n\n`). I want to remove the `\n\n` and concatenate the two strings it separated. 
I.e. `"hello\n\nworld"` becomes `"hello world"`, and not `"hello", "world"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Join with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560863/python-join-with-newline)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
x = ["     hello     \n\n", "world"]
r = " ".join(w.strip() for w in x)
# 'hello world'
```

Note that this removed leading and trailing white space and newlines. If you want to retain leading and trailing white spaces and remove only trailing `"\n"`, you may prefer

```
x = ["     hello     \n\n", "world"]
r = " ".join(w.rstrip("\n") for w in x)
# '     hello      world'
```

Comment: If OP wanted to retain other leading or trailing whitespace then `' '.join(w.rstrip('\n') for w in x)` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you want to remove the sequence of *double* new lines in the input, which I assume means leaving other whitespace untouched:

```
>>> l = ['hello\n\n', 'world']
>>> result = ' '.join(l).replace('\n\n', '')
>>> result
'hello world'
```

This will not perturb any single new lines or other whitespace that might be present in the values of the list, e.g.

```
>>> l = ['   hello\n\n', '  there  \n  ', 'world']
>>> ' '.join(l).replace('\n\n', '')
'   hello   there  \n   world'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_list = ["hello\n\n", "world"]

new_list = []
for item in a_list:
    new_list.append(
        item.replace('\n\n', '')
    )

' '.join(new_list)
```

Comment: This won't work. You need to update the values in the list before applying `join()`, but the list is not updated in the for loop.

Comment: True, just updated. I could have sworn I changed my answer after I posted that lol

Answer (score 0):

Use something like
`mystr = mystr.replace("\n\n"," ").` Then replace old string in list with new joined string.