# Convert a list to a string and back

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a virtual machine which reads instructions from tuples nested within a list like so:

```
[(0,4738),(0,36),
 (0,6376),(0,0)]
```

When storing this kind of machine code program, a text file is easiest, and has to be written as a string. Which is obviously quite hard to convert back.

Is there any module which can read a string into a list/store the list in a readable way?

requirements:

- Must be human readable in stored form (hence "pickle" is not suitable)
- Must be relatively easy to implement

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[JSON!](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
import json

with open(data_file, 'wb') as dump:
    dump.write(json.dumps(arbitrary_data))
```

and similarly:

```
source = open(data_file, 'rb').read()
data = json.loads(source)
```

Answer (score 46):

Use  the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
string = json.dumps(lst)
lst = json.loads(string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> lst = [(0,4738),(0,36),
...  (0,6376),(0,0)]
>>> string = json.dumps(lst)
>>> string
'[[0, 4738], [0, 36], [0, 6376], [0, 0]]'
>>> lst = json.loads(string)
>>> lst
[[0, 4738], [0, 36], [0, 6376], [0, 0]]
```

An alternative could be to use [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) and [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval); for just lists, tuples and integers that also allows you to round-trip:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> string = repr(lst)
>>> string
'[[0, 4738], [0, 36], [0, 6376], [0, 0]]'
>>> lst = literal_eval(string)
>>> lst
[[0, 4738], [0, 36], [0, 6376], [0, 0]]
```

JSON has the added advantage that it is a standard format, with support from tools outside of Python support serialising, parsing and validation. The `json` library is also a lot faster than the `ast.literal_eval()` function.

Answer (score 28):

Just use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> a = literal_eval('[(1, 2)]')
>>> a
[(1, 2)]
```

You can convert it into a string using `repr()`.

```
>>> repr(a)
'[(1, 2)]'
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is how to convert from string to lst and back. The command repr([1,2,3,4]) will create a string, but how do I take this string and convert back to the list

Comment: Using `ast.literal_eval`?

Answer (score 20):

`eval` should do it in a simple way:

```
>>> str([(0,4738),(0,36),(0,6376),(0,0)])
'[(0, 4738), (0, 36), (0, 6376), (0, 0)]'

>>> eval(str([(0,4738),(0,36),(0,6376),(0,0)]))
[(0, 4738), (0, 36), (0, 6376), (0, 0)]
```

Comment: That will work; but might be dangerous. It might allow an attacker to run arbitrary code!
It's better to use the `literal_eval` answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're just dealing with primitive Python types, you can just use the built-in `repr()`:

```
Help on built-in function repr in module __builtin__:

repr(...)
    repr(object) -> string

    Return the canonical string representation of the object.
    For most object types, eval(repr(object)) == object.
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are just two-tuples, you could store them in a CVS file using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). No need for any brackets/parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfile:
     for tup in L:
         outfile.write("%s\n" %' '.join(str(i) for i in tup))

with open('path/to/file) as infile:
    L = [tuple(int(i) for i in line.strip().split()) for line in infile]
```