# Python cant convert 'list' object to str error

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, typeerror

I am using the latest Python 3

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
letters[:3]
print((letters)[:3])
letters[3:]
print((letters)[3:])
print("Here is the whole thing :" + letters)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/Testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    print("Here is the whole thing :" + letters)
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

When fixing, please explain how it works :) i dont want to just copy a fixed line

Comment: I'm as confused as your Python interpreter: What output do you want?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As it currently stands, you are trying to concatenate a string with a list in your final print statement, which will throw `TypeError`.

Instead, alter your last print statement to one of the following:

```
print("Here is the whole thing :" + ' '.join(letters)) #create a string from elements
print("Here is the whole thing :" + str(letters)) #cast list to string
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print("Here is the whole thing : " + str(letters))
```

You have to cast your `List`-object to `String` first.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `str(letters)` method, you can just pass the list as an independent parameter to `print()`. From the `doc` string:

```
>>> print(print.__doc__)
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
```

So multiple values can be passed to `print()` which will print them in sequence, separated by the value of `sep` (`' '` by default):

```
>>> print("Here is the whole thing :", letters)
Here is the whole thing : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> print("Here is the whole thing :", letters, sep='')   # strictly your output without spaces
Here is the whole thing :['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Or you can use string formatting:

```
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> print("Here is the whole thing : {}".format(letters))
Here is the whole thing : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Or string interpolation:

```
>>> print("Here is the whole thing : %s" % letters)
Here is the whole thing : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

These methods are generally preferred over string concatenation with the `+` operator, although it's mostly a matter of personal taste.

Comment: print(str(letters) [3:])   This will work for you