# Printing lists in python without spaces

Tags: python, printing

I am doing a program that changes a number in base 10 to base 7, so i did this :

```
num = int(raw_input(""))
mod = int(0)
list = []
while num> 0:
    mod = num%7
    num = num/7
    list.append(mod)
list.reverse()
for i in range (0,len(list)):
    print list[i],
```

But if the number is 210 it prints 4 2 0  how do i get rid of the spaces

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert list to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string)

Answer (score 15):

You can use join with list comprehension:

```
>>> l=range(5)
>>> print l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> ''.join(str(i) for i in l)
'01234'
```

Also, don't use `list` as a variable name since it is a built-in function.

Comment: Hi thanks it worked fine but im new and i dont undestand how .join works can you give me a simple explanayion

Comment: @mariaalejandraescalante , it takes string as delimiter and concatenates elements in list with each other with delimiter between them. So this ```','.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])``` will give ```'a,b,c'```

Answer (score 8):

In python 3 you can do like this :

```
print(*range(1,int(input())+1), sep='')
```

Your output will be like this if input = 4 :

> 1234

Answer (score 4):

Convert the list to a string, and replace the white spaces.

```
strings = ['hello', 'world']

print strings

>>>['hello', 'world']

print str(strings).replace(" ", "")

>>>['hello','world']
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `sys.stdout`. It's a file object, wrapping standard output. As every file it has `write` method, which takes string, and puts it directly to STDOUT. It also doesn't alter nor add any characters on it's own, so it's handy when you need to fully control your output.

```
>>> import sys
>>> for n in range(8):
...     sys.stdout.write(str(n))
01234567>>>
```

Note two things

- you have to pass string to the function.
- you don't get newline after printing.

Also, it's handy to know that the construct you used:

```
for i in range (0,len(list)):
   print list[i],
```

is equivalent to (frankly a bit more efficient):

```
for i in list:
    print i,
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following worked for me in Python3

```
print(*list,sep='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code snippet for python3

```
print(*list(range(1, n + 1)), sep='')
```

- `*` will remove initial and end character like `[{}]`
- `sep = ''` will remove the spaces between item.

Answer (score 0):

Use list_comprehension.

```
num= int(raw_input(""))
mod=int(0)
list =[]
while num> 0:
    mod=num%7
    num=num/7
    list.append(mod)
list.reverse()
print ''.join([str(list[i]) for i in range (0,len(list))])
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked fine but im new and i dont undestand how .join works can you give me a simple explanayion

Answer (score 0):

The print() function has an argument to specify the end character which by default is '\n'. Specifying the end character as '' and printing using a loop will do what you are looking for:

```
n_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in n_list:
    print(i, end='')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
s = "jay"
list = [ i for i in s ]
```

It you print `list` you will get:

> ['j','a','y']

```
new_s = "".join(list)
```

If you print `new_s`:

> "jay"