# Form list of strings from list of chars in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of chars, something like

```
['t','u','p','l','e']
```

and I want to create a list of Strings out of it:

```
['tuple'
```

I tried to initialise an empty array and append or += to it but this still returns a list of chars. How can I concatenate strings?

Comment: Check [How-to-convert-list-to-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string) for several ways to do it.

Comment: Actually `['t','u','p','l','e']` is already a list of strings.  The strings are of length 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
In [33]: [''.join(['t','u','p','l','e'])]
Out[33]: ['tuple']
```

Comment: I think `''.join(i for i in a)` isn't needed, this will confused OP(because I think OP doesn't know about list comprehension).

Comment: Nit-pick, but the question asked for the result to be a list of strings (presumably always of length 1).  Surrounding the expression with `[]` should be enough.

Comment: @KevinGuan Thanks for suggestion but i just did that to let OP understand what `join` is doing.

Comment: Then as I said that may confused OP, and I think the document is enough.

Comment: @user9515 please mark correct if you find my answer helping.