# How to convert a string list to a proper list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I was trying to solve this problem:

> Write a program that takes two lists and returns a list that contains all the elements of the first list minus all the common elements between the two lists.

The coding part is very simple. Here it is:

```
list1=input()
list2=input()

for i in list1:
  if i in list2:
    list1.remove(i)
  else:
    pass

print(list1)
```

The problem that I face here is that `list1` and `list2` are strings. 
Take `list1=‘[1,2,3,4]’`.

I need to convert `list1` to `[1,2,3,4]`.

I tried `split()` and `join()` methods as suggested in [How to convert list to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string)
but I failed.

How do I convert `'[1,2,3,4]'` to `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: Probably acceptable for this use case: http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

Comment: there is an answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python). please search your problem before asking a new question.

Comment: @9.0 I am so sorry. I did google search the problem but I could not find any solutions. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, you can load it as `json`:

```
import json
json.loads('[1,2,3,4]')
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or you can evaluate the string with `ast.literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval    
literal_eval('[1,2,3,4]')
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any benefit for using one of them over the other?

Comment: `json.loads()` is surprisingly quicker than `ast.literal_eval()` (Py3.6).

Comment: They are slightly different. Except for the performance side @AChampion just noted. The json.loads version is more restrict about the quotes, for instance you can not have single quote around a value because json doesn't accept single quote as valid quoting characters. So ast.literal_eval might be a little more general here.

Answer (score 3):

Eval the string using the `ast` module, which is safe:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3, 4]')
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: What do you mean by ‘safe’? Can’t I use json.loads() which is surprisingly quicker than ast.literal_eval()?

Comment: @AaryanDewan safe as opposed to using `eval()`, which would be another (but unsafe) option - `eval()` doesn't validate its input (which could contain malicious code) whereas `literal_eval()` does. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) for details.

Answer (score -3):

i would convert them right on input
in this case you dont even need to use commas

```
list1=list(input())
list2=list(input())
```

Comment: That would cause a bug. I have tried that

Comment: This will not work, `input()` returns a string the list would contain all the characters in the string, not just the values, e.g. `["'", "[", "1", ",", ...]` not what is being looked for.

Comment: what kind? i just tried ['1', '2', '3', '4'] this was return in inpout 1234

Comment: @oToMaTiX You are probably using Python 2, where `input` passes the input string to `eval` first (making the call to `list` unnecessary). Python 3's `input` is the equivalent of `raw_input`.