# How can I read a string in a file formated as a list into a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string formatted as a list of lists in a file. How can I get this into a variable in Python as a list?

E.g. data-string.txt

```
with open('data-string.txt') as f:
    str = f.read()
```

and

```
str = "[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]"
```

are equivalent.
How can I get this into a real Python list? I have looked into splitting using multiple delimiters, but if that's the right way I haven't been able to set it up correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to do your bidding:

```
import ast
s = ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3]")
s == [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Fantastic. Never heard of abstract syntax trees before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json` for some cases, but @Bharel answer is better at all

```
import json

with open('data-string.txt') as f:
    lst = json.load(f)
    print(lst)  # [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: This actually solves my purpose as well. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
// convert original string to type list
str1 = list("[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]")

// create a new string using the following, which converts same to a 3 x 3 list
str2 = ''.join(str(e) for e in str1)

// prints out as [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string
```