# How to return arrayfield in django model?

Tags: django

This is my models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True))
 def __str__(self):
         return self.product
```

But i'm getting error like :

> TypeError at /admin/ordering/product/add/
>   **str** returned non-string (type list)

Comment: you need to convert it to string to display

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string

Comment: method  __str__ should return string, not list.

Comment: Actually im new to django i just searched how to use arary field in django model and i got this    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert list to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string)

Comment: Actually i want to take the products as array so i have used arrary field but im not getting how to return it as an array instead of str

Comment: First of all welcome to stackoverflow and congratulations for posting a good first question.
you need to manually convert your list to string
simplest way could be to use `return str(self.product)`

Answer (score 0):

In your `__str__()` method of model `Product` self.product returns list of names.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
         return self.product  # This returns list of names
```

You can either convert **self.product** to string manually or replace with following one.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
         return ", ".join(self.product)  # This would join list of names with ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your product array to string. For that you can type cast  product array to string

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True))
 def __str__(self):
         return str(self.product)
```

`str(anything)` will convert any python object into its string representation