# Is there any way to write two values in one name in python

Tags: discord.py

```
f = open("dict.txt","a")
f.write("Customer_Name: "+Name+"\nMovies: "+Movies_Name+"\nQuantity: "+str(quantity)+"\n")
f.close()
```

Movies_Name is a list which might contain more than one movies. Now I want to write the names of the movies individually instead of writing them as a list.

Comment: How is this related to discord.py?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Answer (score 0):

For me it has nothing to do with discord itself. It is just Python question.
So answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/ddg#5618893)

> By using `''.join`
>
> ```
> list1 = ['1', '2', '3']
> str1 = ''.join(list1)
> ```

In your case:

```
f.write("Customer_Name: "+Name+"\nMovies: "+''.join(Movies_Name)+"\nQuantity: "+str(quantity)+"\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very grateful to you.

Comment: @DipRai, you are welcome)