# How can I show the characters only one time - python?

Tags: python

**a = aaabbbbccccdefklmopqwwxxxxxyyyyy**
My question would be, what kind of code should I write in Python in order to:
**b =abcdefklmopqwxy**

so all characters should be appear only once. I am totally newbiew, any answer would be approriated.

Comment: Is order important? Should the new string always be in alphabetical order or in the order of the original string?

Comment: [How to convert list to string [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string) [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("".join(sorted(set("aaabbbbccccdefklmopqwwxxxxxyyyyy"))))
```

Output:

```
abcdefklmopqwxy
```

As suggest in the comments by [@Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209921/matthias) you can get the job done with `itertools`, but this time the order is based on the original string.

```py
import itertools
print(''.join(g[0] for g in itertools.groupby("aaabbbbccccdefklmopqwwxxxxxyyyyy")))
```

Output:

```
abcdefklmopqwxy
```

Comment: This assumes that the order of the output will always be alphabetical rather than the order of the original string.

Comment: `itertools` to the rescue: `b = ''.join(g[0] for g in itertools.groupby(a))`