# Remove beginning and ending " from a string and store as variable

Tags: python, string, list, global-variables, slice

I have a simple python list below called lis

```
    lis = ['CWA9','WQH0','GBD0']
```

When I print and slice the list, I get the format I desire, but cannot figure how to store as a variable

```
    print (str(lis)[1:-1])

    'CWA9','WQH0','GBD0'
```

I tried the following, but I get the beginning and ending " marks (string format).

```
    str(lis)[1:-1]

    "'CWA9','WQH0','GBD0'"
```

Whats the best approach to format the original list (lis) to the format seen in the print code above so that the output is 'CWA9','WQH0','GBD0' and store as a variable

Comment: `'CWA9','WQH0','GBD0'` are 3 values. What do you mean by store it as *a* variable?

Comment: That's how Python represents the string, so you know it's a string. It's not part of the string, it's part of the representation of the string.

Comment: You *already have* what are you trying to get

Comment: 1. variable meaning stored in memory so it can be passed through further in program. Var would be 'CWA9','WQH0','GBD0'.  2.  Yes, " " is string representation, how do I store without " "? I need  it stored without " "

Comment: It is not stored with "". The "" is just shown when you do print! Look at my answer below. I print the first character and it is the single quote, not the double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: You can do

```
lis = ['CWA9','WQH0','GBD0']
lis = [f"'{x}'" for x in lis] #New line in update
lis = ', '.join(lis)
```

then `print(lis)` gives

```
'CWA9', 'WQH0', 'GBD0'
```

Comment: If this is really the only objective, then this is clearly a duplicate question of many others, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string

Comment: Hi there Jonatan. Thanks for the response. My apologies, I should have been more specific there. I would need it to be with quotes so that it would read 'CWA9','WQH0','GBD0'. I need so I can pass it through the in clause in SQL so that

Comment: select * from table where var in ( '' , ''  , '').

Comment: @brodo80 put what you're trying to achieve in the question. If you're using sqlite you should let it populate the SQL for you.

Comment: this is an x/y problem

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes are not part of the output. You can check it by:

```
lis = ['CWA9','WQH0','GBD0']

a = str(lis)[1:-1]

a[0]
```

This will print:

```
"'"
```

Which means your first character is actually the single quote. Double quotes are only printed to let you know it is a string.