# How can I concatenate [['a'],['b'],['c']] this form of list into one string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have this list:

```
[['abcde'],['defgh'],['dfsdf']]
```

And I want this result:

```
'abcdedefghdfsdf'
```

I want a simple solution.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate after nearly 14 years and [1,942,974 Python questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)? Why do people keep answering the same beginner questions over and over and over again?

Comment: `str(reduce(lambda x,y: "".join(["".join(x), "".join(y)]), [['abcde'],['defgh'],['dfsdf']]))` this is also good

Comment: Candidates: *[How do I concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-do-i-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)* (2012) and *[How to convert list to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string)* (2011). There must be plenty both before and after that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this in one line:

```
"".join([i[0] for i in a])
```

It will loop over the items and turns them into  `['abcde','defgh','dfsdf']`. Then you will concatenate them with *join*.

So the result will be:

```
Out[4]: 'abcdedefghdfsdf'
```

Take a look at [this link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join) to learn more about `.join()`.

As [FreddyMcloughlan said in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72152508/how-can-i-concate-a-b-c-this-form-of-list-into-one-string-in-pytho#comment127484146_72152517):

> You could change the square brackets to parenthesis to turn it into a generator if working with very large lists

Comment: You could change the square brackets to parenthesis to turn it into a generator if working with very large lists

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan nice Idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try this snippet:

```
str_lists = [['abcde'],['defgh'],['dfsdf']]
output_str = "".join([lst.pop() for lst in str_lists])
```

"".join() is used to concatenate strings together from a list, while the inner list comprehension is used to flatten the list of lists into a single list